# How to move cursor to the end of the TextField after screen rotation or system theme change and keep keyboard shown?

Tags: android, keyboard, focus, android-jetpack-compose, material3

I have a screen with a `Textfield` as a Search bar which is autofocused when the screen is first displayed. The problem is, after `screen rotation` or `system theme change` (Dark mode/light mode), the `cursor` moves at the beginning of TextField even if the value of TextField is not empty and the keyboard dismisses itself. Please help, I've been searching for two days. Some code samples:

Compose version: 1.3.0
Material 3: 1.0.0

SearchBookScreen.kt

```
val myViewModel = SearchBookViewModel()

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SearchBookScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: SearchBookViewModel = myViewModel,
    filters: Map<SearchFilterType, FilterOptions> = FILTERS
) {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() } 

val searchInputValue = viewModel.searchInputValue.value
val filtersState = viewModel.filtersState

LaunchedEffect(Unit) { this.coroutineContext.job.invokeOnCompletion { focusRequester.requestFocus() } }

Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        Column {
            TextField(
                singleLine = true,
                placeholder = {
                    Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.search_bar))
                },
                value = searchInputValue.text,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                    ,
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.onEvent(SearchBookEvent.EnteredSearchValue(it))
                },
                leadingIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        viewModel.onEvent(SearchBookEvent.ClearSearchInput)
                        navController.navigateUp()
                    }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "Go back"
                        )
                    }
                },
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
                ),
                trailingIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { viewModel.onEvent(SearchBookEvent.ClearSearchInput) }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Clear, contentDescription = "clear")
                    }
                },
            )
```

SearchBookViewModel.kt

```
class SearchBookViewModel: ViewModel() {


private val _searchInputValue = mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("", selection = TextRange.Zero))
val searchInputValue: State<TextFieldValue> = _searchInputValue


 fun onEvent(event: SearchBookEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is SearchBookEvent.EnteredSearchValue -> {
                _searchInputValue.value = searchInputValue.value.copy(text = event.value, selection = TextRange(event.value.length))
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the selection, the issue is here,

```
value = searchInputValue.text
```

your'e manipulating text using `TextFieldValue` but you are just updating the `TextField` value parameter using ordinary `String` (TextFieldValue's text property), anything you do with the `TextFieldValue` instance is not reflecting to your `TextField`.

I made some modifications in your code by using the `State<TextFieldValue>'s` delegate

```
val searchInputValue by viewModel.searchInputValue
```

and used it as the actual value instead of its `text` property to your `TextField` like this.

```
value = searchInputValue
```

However you have to modify how it is being updated, so I modify `onValueChange` as well, I only used `.text` as I don't want to modify other parts further and to leave it for you to change it.

```
 onValueChange = {
    viewModel.onEvent(SearchBookEvent.EnteredSearchValue(it.text))
 }
```

Your `TextField` implementation should look like this

```
TextField(
      singleLine = true,
      placeholder = {
            Text(text = "Type Here")
      },
      value = searchInputValue, // <- notice this
      modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .focusRequester(focusRequester),
      onValueChange = {  
             viewModel.onEvent(SearchBookEvent.EnteredSearchValue(it.text)) // <- and this
      }
```

Apply all these changes and when you switch theme mode, the cursor/selection will stay at the end.

Now for the keyboard issue, showing it initially, I had to implement something from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72783455/jetpack-compose-outlinedtextfield-gets-focus-but-no-keyboard-show-up) adding a delay prior to requesting focus,

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    delay(200)
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
}
```

and to retain the keyboard while changing theme mode, I had to specify this in my activity.

```
window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNCHANGED)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @z.y, it works !! But instead of passing the text to the view model, I passed the entire TextFieldValue (searchInputValue). When I  pass only the text, It produces some kind of infinite logs in LogCat